# echo a session variable in a <a href> over to the next page?

Tags: php, mysql, session, hyperlink

Please can someone help me with this. I have this MySQL query which lists users on my site, and echos a link that can be clicked to take you to the user's profile:

```
<?php
        $online_set = online_channel();
        while ($online = mysql_fetch_array($online_set)) {
            echo "<div class=\"online_row\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$online['user_id']}\"><img width=25px height=25px src=\"data/photos/{$online['user_id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"online_image\"/><div class=\"online_text\">{$online['display_name']}</div></a></div>";?>
            <? } ?>
```

The link goes to profile.php and echos the users 'user_id' so it knows which users profile to take you to, and now I am wanting to include a session variable in the link somehow so a message is displayed on that users profile after clicking the link.

I have tried including `$_SESSION['chat']` in the link but it doesn't work:

```
 <?php
            $online_set = online_channel();
            while ($online = mysql_fetch_array($online_set)) {
                echo "<div class=\"online_row\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$online['user_id']}{$_SESSION['chat']}\"><img width=25px height=25px src=\"data/photos/{$online['user_id']}/_default.jpg\" class=\"online_image\"/><div class=\"online_text\">{$online['display_name']}</div></a></div>";?>
                <? } ?>
```

I am also trying to execute the session in profile.php by using this:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['chat']))
   echo $_SESSION['chat']="<div class=\"infobox-favourites\"><strong>Deleted from Favourites</strong> - This user has successfully been deleted from your favourites.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>"; 
    unset($_SESSION['chat']);

?>
```

What I have tried is not working and i'm not sure i'm doing it right, so I would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: Did you check if you get results out of your query?

Comment: yes i get results out of my query, im just not sure if it's possible to add two echo's like i have done :(

Comment: have you looked at the PHP session_id function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: This does not seem right in the last block of code: 
`echo $_SESSION['chat']=".....` Just echo out the string.

Comment: Also make sure you include the quotes in the html attributes.
`id=" "`.
Better is to concatenate with PHP: 
`echo "<div id='" . $var . "'></div>";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...for easier debugging the entire code you have

```
<?php
            $online_set = online_channel();
            while ($online = mysql_fetch_array($online_set)) {
                ?>
                <div class="online_row">
                    <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $online['user_id'];?>">
                        <img width=25px height=25px src="data/photos/<?php echo $online['user_id'];?>/_default.jpg/" class="online_image" />
                        <div class="online_text\">
                            <?php echo $online['display_name'];?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
?>
```

Just review the code I posted to learn the better way to echo an entire div